# How can I append an empty array field into a JSON if a JSON field is null?

Tags: javascript, json

I am not so into JavaScript and I have this problem (I can solve it only using pure old JS and not third party library).

I have a JavaScript script processing a JSON object, in my script I have:

```
if(finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo == null) {
    log.info("NO SUBSPECIES");
    finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo.SubSpeciesList = [];
}
```

that check if this property of my original JSON object is null:

```
"SubSpeciesInfo": null
```

If this property of my JSON object is null it enter into the if block.

What I have to do here is to append the **SubSpeciesList** sub field that is an empty list.

But in this way it is not working, I obtain an error like:

```
 ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} -  The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator}
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot set property "SubSpeciesList" of null to "org.mozilla.javascript.NativeArray@37aa205f" (<Unknown Source>#106) in <Unknown Source> at line number 106
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
```

What is the problem? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign an object with a new property for the array, because you try to use a property `SubSpeciesList`, which does not exist.

```
if (finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo === null) {
    log.info("NO SUBSPECIES");
    finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo = { SubSpeciesList: [] };
}
```

For a comparison without type coercion use better `===` for a strict check. Read more: [Strict equality using `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

**DEMO**

```js
var finalResponse = {
  SubSpeciesInfo : null 
}

if(finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo === null) {
    console.log("NO SUBSPECIES");
    finalResponse.SubSpeciesInfo = {SubSpeciesList : []};
}

console.log(finalResponse);
```